What am I missing or need to update in my Plaid Integration code?
I am currently working on updating a class for integration in Salesforce, in this case, an API call from the banking (I think) service called Plaid. The company already integrated this app, but right now I am required to update it to make an API call for the endpoint '/identity_verification/create'.
Right now I have good code coverage (87%) but I get an error in the method test class when it gets the result of 'System.assertEquals', the expected result it should be. the endpoint mentioned before but it is actual = null. I also feel that I have things to correct.
Here is what I have added/updated in the class right now:
 public class PlaidUser {
    
    public String client_id { get; set; }
    public String secret    { get; set; }
    public Boolean is_shareable { get; set; }
    public Boolean gave_consent { get; set; }
    public String template_id { get; set;}
    public String given_name { get; set; }
    public String family_name {get; set;}
    public String country { get; set;}
    public String id_number_value { get; set;}
    public String id_number_type { get; set;}
    public String shareable_url { get; set; }
    public DateTime dob = DateTime.newInstance(Date.newInstance(1988, 01, 01), Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0));
        
}

//Method to create a Plaid user request
 public static PlaidUser PlaidUserRequest(String userInfo) {
    PlaidUser request = new PlaidUser();
    Http http = new Http();
    String url = '/identity_verification/create';
    
    
    //Body request
    String bodyRequest = '{ client_id: "' + CLIENT_ID + '", ' +
        'secret: "' + SECRET + '", ' +
        'shareable_url: "' + request.shareable_url + '", ' +
        '"isShareable": true, ' +
        '"templateId": "template_Id", ' +
        '"gaveConsent": true, ' +
        '"user": { ' + 
        '"dateofBirth": "' + request.dob + '", ' +
        '"name": { ' +
        '"fName": "' + request.given_name + '", ' +
        '"lName": "' + request.family_name + '", ' +
        '}, ' +
        '"address": { ' +
        '"country": "' + request.country + '", ' +
        '}, ' +
        '"idNumber": { ' + 
        '"value": "' + request.id_number_value + '", ' +
        '"type": "' + request.id_number_type + '", ' +
        '}}';
        
    String body = bodyRequest;
    
    HttpResponse res = callout(url, body);
    
    if(res.getStatusCode() != 200) {
        String format = 'Unexpected HTTP Response: {0}:{1}\n\n{2}';
        String[] parts = new String[]
        {
            String.valueOf(res.getStatusCode()),
            res.getStatus(),
            res.getBody()
        };
        String message = String.format(format, parts);
        throw new CalloutException(message);
    }
    
    return
        (Plaid.PlaidUser) JSON.deserialize
        (res.getBody(), Plaid.PlaidUser.class);
        
}

And here is the update that I have made in the test class:
public class MockHttpResponse implements HttpCalloutMock {
    
    private Integer code;
    
    //Using example from PlaidRemoveItemMock for a failed response
    public MockHttpResponse(Integer code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    
    public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest req) {            
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setStatusCode(code);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint('/identity_verification/create');
        
        String body;
        if(code == 200) {
            body = '{"client_Id": 12345, "request_id": "blah"}';
        } else {
            body = 'Failure';
        }
        res.setBody(body);
        return res;
    }
}

@isTest
public static void testPlaidUserFailure() {
    MockHttpResponse mock = new MockHttpResponse(500);
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);
    
    Test.startTest();
    try{
        Plaid.PlaidUser response = Plaid.PlaidUserRequest('Plaid User Failed');
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.assert(e.getMessage().startsWith('Unexpected HTTP Response: 500'));
    }
    Test.stopTest();
}

@isTest
public static void testPlaidUserSuccess() {
    MockHttpResponse mock = new MockHttpResponse(200);
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);
    
    Test.startTest();
    Plaid.PlaidUser response = Plaid.PlaidUserRequest('userInfo');
    System.assertEquals('12345', response.client_Id);
    Test.stopTest();
}

 @isTest
public static void testPlaidUserRequest() {
    //Setup test data
    Plaid.PlaidUser UserInfo = new Plaid.PlaidUser();
    UserInfo.given_name = 'Plaid';
    UserInfo.family_name = 'User';
    UserInfo.is_shareable = true;
    UserInfo.gave_consent = true;
    UserInfo.country = 'US';
    UserInfo.id_number_type = 'us_ssn';
    UserInfo.id_number_value = '111-22-3333';
    UserInfo.secret = 'secret';
    UserInfo.template_id = 'templated_id';
    
    //Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new testPlaidUserRequest());
    //HttpResponse response = Plaid.callout(url, body);

    //Verifying that HTTP request is informed
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('/identity_verification/create');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    
    System.assertEquals('/identity_verification/create', req.getEndpoint(), 'Success');
    System.assertEquals('application/json', req.getHeader('Content-Type'), 'Success');
    System.assertEquals('POST', req.getMethod(), 'Success');

    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    System.assertEquals(200, res.getStatusCode(), 'Success');
    
}

Thank you for your feedback in advance!


I assume you are referring to the assert, where you test "req.getEndpoint()"?! The sentence containing "... the expected result it should be. the..." is not 100% clear. getEndpoint() must necessarily return null, because the endpoint is nowhere set. 2. I'd suggest not to modify the HttpRequest (set method and endpoint) in the HttpCalloutMock. This should be done in the method that constructs the HttpRequest. The idea of the mock is rather to behave differently for different request methods and endpoints.



We've got a proper class Assert (see here) now - better than System.assert. 4. If you use try-catch in unit tests (like in testPlaidUserFailure()), make sure the unit test actually executes the catch branch by inserting some Assert.fail as the last line in the try branch.


@FelixvanHove thank you for your comments, I have made the changes since you are right, I never declared the endpoint nor method, but I have added them in the method class, please see the original post and let me know if that's correct.
Also, sorry if it is a dumb question but this is my first time working with API calls, but my supervisor tested it and had errors and mentioned that I need to send information about the user in the request. Seeing the class, where should I do that? Using the Http HTTP = new Http(); ????
